# How to set the property $label_hidden to be true

Tags: 7, theming, search

In the `field.tpl.php` the following code:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

The code is printing the label of the field. I want to set, conditionally,  `$label_hidden = false` from more general place other than the `field.tpl.php` itself.

I tried the following snippet from template.php:

```
function my_foundation_preprocess_field(&$variables){
  print_r($variables);
}
```

To get the value I mean but all I found is `[#label_display] => hidden` as an array element. In addition, the form I meant with is not found in that array, the search form.

So I need a way to set $label_hidden = true to prevent the Search label of the search text box.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are handled differently than the variables, like node content, etc. You can find information on customising the Search form [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/154137). A common method for hiding the label is to use CSS and simply make it display:none. It's exact nomenclature will depend on how exactly you have implemented the search form.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link you regarded about `_form_alter()`, it does not solve my issue. It has no any access to the `label` tag before the search input text in the search form. However, partially, it could be solved by defining the css class `.element-invisible` in my theme css and set its display to be none.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what "label" you are referring to and want to remove?

Comment: the screen shot at the following link: http://tinypic.com/r/nzhc2e/8

Comment: it kind of looks like a block title perhaps?  go to admin/structure/block and find the search block for the appropriate theme. click on configure, and see if the block has that title. To show no title, type <none> in the title